# Javascript: addEventListener for transitionend does not execute function

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, transitionend

I have the following code which is supposed to make a banner fade into view, which it does. However, there are additional effects I want to trigger once the transition has completed, but I cannot get the *transitionend* event to trigger a call to a function.

```
  modalBanner.classList.remove("fade-in", "fade-out");
  modalBanner.classList.add("hidden");
  modalBanner.innerHTML = bannerText;
  if (bannerText != "") {
    console.log("adding transition");
    modalBanner.classList.add("fade-in");
    var qs = document.querySelector('.fade-in');
    console.log(qs);
    qs.addEventListener("transitionend", () => { console.log('Transition ended'); });   
    modalBanner.classList.remove("hidden");
    console.log("transition added");
  }
```

I am executing this in Chrome v93, which [this](https://caniuse.com/?search=transitionend) site says supports *transitionend*.
My console log shows:

```
adding transition                          ​GameTracker.html:288
 <div class=​"modalBanner fade-in">​…​</div>  ​GameTracker.html:291
transition added                           GameTracker.html:294
>
```

As you can see, the *fade-in* class does get added, and the *fade-in* does work. But I never get the *Transition ended* message.
Any ideas as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: The call to `.querySelector()` will return only the **first** element in the DOM that has the given class.

Comment: please add a [**Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Pointy good point. But in this case it is returning the correct element. I have verified that by showing the value for qs, which is showing the correct modalBanner div element.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

**Good Greif!** I found the problem. I was posting a comment to include my css for the *fade-in* effect and noticed that the css is using *animation*, not *transition*. I had forgotten that I had changed the css some time ago.

I switched the javascript to use `addEventListener("animationend"...` and it worked.